# How can I debug manually typed expression and statements in pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, expression, pdb

In pdb (or ipdb) we can execute statements and evaluate expressions with the [`!` or `p` commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

> p expression
>        Evaluate the expression in the current context and print its value.
>
> [!]statement
>
> Execute the (one-line) statement in the context of the current stack frame. The exclamation point can be omitted unless the first word of the statement resembles a debugger command. To set a global variable, you can prefix the assignment command with a global command on the same line

So, for example, I can type `p reddit.get_subreddits()` while debugging in ipdb and the code will be executed in the current context and I will see the return value.

Is there a way I can debug the execution of such "manually typed" expressions?

Basically I would like to do is `s reddit.get_subreddits()`, but that just executes the `step` command and ignores the expression.

**EDIT: A trivial example**

Take this simple function:

```
import random

def get_value_for_weekday(weekday_index=None):
    values = [10, 20, 20, 10, 30, 30, 30]
    if not weekday_index:
        # If no weekday provided, return the average of all weekdays
        return sum(values) / 7
    return averages[weekday_index]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()  # enter ipbd for debug
        get_value_for_weekday(random.randint(0, 7))
```

Which is bugged because of the `if not weekday_index` (it should check `weekday_index is not None`.)

Let's assume I notice I get `10` half the number of times I was expecting. So I added a `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` before the call to the function to try and debug the code.

So I'm in the ipdb console and I suddenly get the idea that maybe the problem is when I pass 0 as weekday_index.
I can test my hypothesis directly in  ipdb:

```
ipdb> p get_value_for_weekday(0)
22
```

Ok, so I realize there's something wrong when `weekday_index=0`.
What I would like to do now is debug step by step the call to `get_value_for_weekday(0)`, so that I could see that I erranously enter the if block.

Obviously I could exit ipdb, stop the script, change the code to always pass 0, relaunch the script and when I enter ipdb, debug the call with the ipdb `step` (`s`) command.
But wouldn't it be easier if I could just do `s get_value_for_weekday(0)` much the same way I was able to do `p get_value_for_weekday(0)`?

Is there a way do something like this?

Comment: Could you give a more tangible examble which I could reproduce? I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Added an example, I hope it makes thing clearer.

Answer (score 12):

I think you're looking for the `(d)ebug` command which, for some reason, is not specified in the [*Debugger Commands*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands). Just for future reference, `pdb` has a nice set of commands specified (which you can see by typing `help` in the interactive prompt). On to the `debug` command:

```
(Pdb) help debug
debug code
        Enter a recursive debugger that steps through the code
        argument (which is an arbitrary expression or statement to be
        executed in the current environment).
```

Which seems to do what you're after. Using your sample script from the terminal:

```
python -m pdb pdbscript.py
```

After issuing two `n` commands in order for the function to get parsed (I believe this is how `pdb` works). You can issue a `debug get_value_for_weekday(0)` command to recursively step in the function:

```
(Pdb) debug get_value_for_weekday(0)
ENTERING RECURSIVE DEBUGGER
> <string>(1)<module>()
((Pdb)) s
--Call--
> /home/jim/Desktop/pdbscript.py(3)get_value_for_weekday()
-> def get_value_for_weekday(weekday_index=None):
((Pdb)) n
> /home/jim/Desktop/pdbscript.py(4)get_value_for_weekday()
-> values = [10, 20, 20, 10, 30, 30, 30]
((Pdb)) n 
> /home/jim/Desktop/pdbscript.py(5)get_value_for_weekday()
-> if not weekday_index:
((Pdb)) p weekday_index
0
((Pdb)) n
> /home/jim/Desktop/pdbscript.py(7)get_value_for_weekday()
-> return sum(values) / 7
```

Do note, *I feel really sketchy about this form of meta-debugging* but it seems to be what you're after.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @LeartS I'm glad! Like I noted though, I really feel weird about embedded debuggers; thinking about them makes my head hurt a bit.

Comment: Good answer. Out of curiosity, what is it about embedded debuggers that makes you feel uncomfortable? :)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your example, 
you don't need to exit pdb and change the code.
You can step into the function (with 's') and set weekday_index=0 inside.

One solution to your original problem is to use the debugger's jump command as follows:

1. jump before the function call using 'j #line-number'
2. step in the function with 's'
3. set the input params, and continue debugging.

This worked when I tried it, but the debugger complained when I tried to do step 3 before step 2 for some reason.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to debug a function call I will step into it later, maybe another function call (one I will not step into but could have side effects or help me understand the code in some way). I guess my example was not that good.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if this is possible with ipdb.

Comment: A different solution to your problem is to use the debugger's jump command as follows: (1) jump before the function call using 'j #line-number' (2) step in the function with 's'  (3) set the input params and continue debugging.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer?