# How to use the 'debug' command inside pdb (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pdb

I would like to know how to use the `debug` command in pdb?

```
(Pdb) help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    c          d        h         list      q        rv       undisplay
a      cl         debug    help      ll        quit     s        unt
alias  clear      disable  ignore    longlist  r        source   until
args   commands   display  interact  n         restart  step     up
b      condition  down     j         next      return   tbreak   w
break  cont       enable   jump      p         retval   u        whatis
bt     continue   exit     l         pp        run      unalias  where

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
pdb  exec
(Pdb) help debug
debug code
        Enter a recursive debugger that steps through the code
        argument (which is an arbitrary expression or statement to be
        executed in the current environment).
(Pdb) debug print('hello')
ENTERING RECURSIVE DEBUGGER
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
((Pdb)) n
hello
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
((Pdb)) n
LEAVING RECURSIVE DEBUGGER
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question confused me years. I always forgot to search the final answer. But today I get it, and share what I find here.

[How can I debug manually typed expression and statements in pdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769636/how-can-i-debug-manually-typed-expression-and-statements-in-pdb)

**When you are in the recursive debug mode first time, type `s` , you will kwon what to do the next.**

Comment: Finally I understand the purpose and how to use this option! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Let, you have a bunch of code. You put pdb, say line 3.

In this case, when you run the program, line 1 and line 2 is executed automatically and you can see the result by putting the variable name and from line 4 is not executed.

If you wanna see after line 3 result you have to write code which results you want to see or you can go next line using `n`, and `c` for continuing that means exit from debugging mode.

Comment: Thanks @Shaon but I do understand how to debug with Python but there is one command `debug` (see help command)  that I don't understand. Do you have an example of how to use the `debug` command