# How to step into code that is executed from within PDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pdb

Suppose I start pdb by executing `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` from within the code.

Now I have an interpreter available, and I can step through the underlying code with pdb commands (e.g. `n`, `s`, `u`, `d` etc.).

However, I want to evaluate some code which is *not in the underlying file*. Is it possible to step into *that* code?

Comment: What code exactly? You might be looking for `debug`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769636/how-can-i-debug-manually-typed-expression-and-statements-in-pdb/34864224#34864224).

Comment: `debug` is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Great, though you could delete this question, I could alternatively mark it as a duplicate. That way there's more ways to reach the other question that solves this issue. What do you want to do?

Comment: Probably duplicate?

Comment: That's the best choice, cammil. Marked it as such :-)